# Ctrl+I produces Tab character instead of italizing text

Tags: texstudio, italic, keyboard

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Xfce 4.8. Only in some applications, namely TexStudio (v2.6.6) and TexMaker (v4.1), Ctrl+I inserts one Tab character instead of making text italic.

How do I troubleshoot such a keyboard shortcut (mapping) issue?

Answer (score 4):

Control I *is* Tab (I is character code 73 and control subtracts 64 leaving character code 9 which is TAB). Whether that code inserts a character into your document or does something in your editor depends on your editor. Personally I have never used an editor where Ctrl-i makes anything italic, but there may be one I suppose.

Comment: Never used Ctrl+i for italic? Open Office has this shortcut (at least in my version). Also, my TeXstudio has it.

Comment: @Sigur I've used Open Office (and MS Office) as document viewers but never produced a document in either, and I use emacs for everything else, where ^I just runs whatever command is bound to TAB, usually some kind of indent command, depending on the mode.

Comment: Sometimes I have to fill some reports and forms using `doc` files (unfortunately). This is the rule in my university. You're a luck man. lol

Comment: Thank you David for the explanation. BTW, I also believe that being independent from the editor is a good practice..

Answer (score 2):

I'm using *TeXstudio 2.6.2 (SVN 4111) Using Qt Version 4.7.4, compiled with Qt 4.7.4 D* on Lubuntu 11.10.

As you can see on the image, the shortcut to Italic is in fact Ctrl+i. You can change it using the Options menu.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sigur. All the shortcuts are untouched. For some reason, probably a bug in Xfce, I noted that some other keyboard shortcuts (like Ctrl+O) are not working too. I switched back to Gnome desktop and everything is fine now.